# handling large dataset using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to apply for a job, which asks for the experiences on handling large scale data sets using relational database, like mySQL.

I would like to know which specific skill sets are required for handling large scale data using MySQL.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the job is for you!

Comment: I have to second @James C here. If you're interested in a job like that in the *future* and want to know what it might entail, then great question. But it's a very bad idea to decide to apply for a job *THEN* figure out what the description means.

Comment: I once met a guy who had bullshitted his way into a job as a high-voltage electrical engineer, working at a power station. He regretted it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Handling large scale data with MySQL isn't just a specific set of skills, as there are a bazillion ways to deal with a large data set.  Some basic things to understand are:

- [Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/column-indexes.html), how, why, and when they're used, and the pros and cons of using them.
- Good database structure to balance between fast writes and easy reads.
- Caching, leveraging several layers of caching and different caching technologies ([memcached](http://memcached.org/), [redis](http://redis.io), etc)
- Examining MySQL queries to identify bottlenecks and understanding the MySQL internals to see how queries get planned an executed by the database server in order to increase query performance
- Configuring the MySQL server to be able to handle a lot of concurrent connections, and access it's data fast.  Hardware bottlenecks, and the advantages to using different technologies to speed up your hardware (for example, storing your MySQL data on a [RAID5 Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_5) to increase IO performance))
- Leveraging built-in MySQL technology (like [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)) to off-load read traffic

These are just a few things that get thought about in regards to big data in MySQL.  There's a TON more, which is why the company is looking for experience in the area.  Knowing what to do, or having experience with things that have worked or failed for you is an absolutely invaluable asset to bring to a company that deals with high traffic, high availability, and high volume services.

**edit**
I would be remis if I didn't mention a source for more information.  Check out [High Performance MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003064).  This is an incredible book, and has a plethora of information on how to make MySQL perform in all scenarios.  Definitely worth the money, and the time spent reading it.

**edit  -- good structure for balanced writes and reads**

With this point, I was referring to the topic of normalization / de-normalization.  If you're familiar with DB design, you know that normalization is the separation of data as to reduce (eliminate) the amount of duplicate data you have about any single record.  This is generally a fantastic idea, as it makes tables smaller, faster to query, easier to index (individually) and reduces the number of writes you have to do in order to create/update a new record.

There are different levels of normalization (as @Adam Robinson pointed out in the comments below) which are referred to as [normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms).  Almost every web application I've worked with hasn't had much benefit beyond the 3NF (3rd Normal Form).  Which the definition of, if you were to read that wikipedia link above, will probably make your head hurt.  So in lamens (at the risk of dumbing it down too far...) a 3NF structure satisfies the following rules:

1. No duplicate columns within the same table.
2. Create different tables for each set related data. (Example: a `Companies` table which has a list of companies, and an `Employees` table which has a list of each companies' employees)
3. No sub-sets of columns which apply to multiple rows in a table. (Example: `zip_code`, `state`, and `city` is a sub-set of data which can be identified uniquely by `zip_code`. These 3 columns could be put in their own table, and referenced by the `Employees` table (in the previous example) by the `zip_code`).  This eliminates large sets of duplication within your tables, so any change that is required to the city/state for any zip code is a single write operation instead of 1 write for every employee who lives in that zip code.
4. Each sub-set of data is moved to it's own table and is identified by it's own primary key (this is touched/explained in the example for #3).
5. Remove columns which are not fully dependent on the primary key. (An example here might be if your `Employees` table has `start_date`, `end_date`, and `years_employed` columns.  The `start_date` and `end_date` are both unique and dependent on any single employee row, but the `years_employed` can be derived by subtracting `start_date` from `end_date`.  This is important because as end-date increases, so does `years_employed` so if you were to update `end_date` you'd also have to update `years_employed` (2 writes instead of 1)

A fully normalized (3NF) database table structure is great, if you've got a very heavy write-load.  If your server is doing a lot of writes, it's very easy to write small bits of data, especially when you're running fewer of them.  The drawback is, all your reads become much more expensive, because you have to (typically) run a lot of `JOIN` queries when you're pulling data out.  `JOIN`s are typically expensive and harder to create proper indexes for when you're utilizing `WHERE` clauses that span the relationship and when sorting the result-sets  If you have to perform a lot of reads (`SELECT`s) on your data-set, using a 3NF structure can cause you some performance problems.  This is because as your tables grow you're asking MySQL to cram more and more table data (and indexes) into memory.  Ideally this is what you want, but with big data-sets you're just not going to have enough memory to fit all of this at once.  This is when MySQL starts to create temporary tables, and has to use the disk to load data and manipulate it.  Once MySQL becomes reliant on the hard disk to serve up query results you're going to see a significant performance drop.  This is less-so the case with solid state disks, but they are super expensive, and (imo) are not mature enough to use on mission critical data sets yet (i mean, unless you're prepared for them to fail and have a very fast backup recovery system in place...then use them and gonuts!).

This is the balancing part.  You have to decide what kind of traffic the data you're reading/writing is going to be serving more of, and design that to be fast.  In some instances, people don't mind writes being slow because they happen less frequently.  In other cases, writes have to be very fast, and the reads don't have to be fast because the data isn't accessed that often (or at all, or even in real time).

Workloads that require a lot of reads benefit the most from a middle-tier caching layer.  The idea is that your writes are still fast (because you're 'normal') and your reads can be slow because you're going to cache it (in memcached or something competitive to it), so you don't hit the database very frequently.  The drawback here is, if your cache gets invalidated quickly, then the cache is not reducing the read load by a meaningful amount and that results in no added performance (and possibly even more overhead to check/invalidate the caches).

With workloads that have the requirement for high throughput in writes, with data that is read frequently, and can't be cached (constantly changes), you have to come up with another strategy.  This could mean that you start to de-normalize your tables, by removing some of the normalization requirements you choose to satisfy, or something else.  Instead of making smaller tables with less repetitive data, you make larger tables with more repetitive / redundant data.  The advantage here is that your data is all in the same table, so you don't have to perform as many (or, any) `JOIN`s to pull the data out.  The drawback...writes are more expensive because you have to write in multiple places.

So with any given situation the developer(s) have to identify what kind of use the data structure is going to have to serve, and balance between any number of technologies and paradigms to achieve an acceptable solution that meets their needs.  No two systems or solutions are the same which is why the employer is looking for someone with experience on how to deal with these large datasets.  Finding these solutions is not something that can really be learned out of a book, it typically takes some experience in the field and experience with how different solutions performed.

I hope that helps.  I know I rambled a bit, but it's really a lot of information.  This is why DBAs make the big dollars (:

Comment: Jim, thanks for the detailed reply. With respecit to the second item you mentioned, "Good database structure to balance between fast writes and easy reads", can you list some reference on it?

Comment: @user297850 no problem.  I added more detail on the item you asked about; it's long, so brace yourself (:

Comment: -1 "JOINs are typically expensive and harder to create proper indexes for" At the risk of being rude here, that is *terrible* and *completely incorrect* advice. Joins on clustered indexes (which means joining to another table based on its primary key, unless you've explicitly NOT clustered the primary key) are incredibly fast (binary search goes directly to the data page), and joins on non-clustered indexes are almost as fast. While database optimization can be a complex science, the implication that figuring out how to create indexes that are optimized for joins is more difficult is silly.

Comment: (cont.) If it weren't for your casual disregard for normalization (and not explaining what you mean by "fully normalized". Do you mean to 3NF (which usually means 4NF anyway)? 5NF? 6NF?), this would have gotten a +1 from me.

Comment: Typically when JOINing across multiple tables, you're also creating WHERE clauses that span the JOIN.  When you start to join multiple tables and issue WHERE clauses on them, you're asking MySQL to put all of the data sets and indexes for them in memory.  This, against large datasets, just isn't possible.  And this is what causes JOIN expense.  I admit the explanation is probably counter to that, I'll fix it.  I was not implying that creating the linking columns between two tables is hard or expensive - it's all the other data implications that come along with using JOINs in the first place.

Comment: I should also add, I'm not advocating completely de-normalizing a database.  I will cling to a normalized structure until the bitter end. De-normalization causes so much more work, and I am far too lazy to volunteer to manage it willingly. haha.

Comment: @Jim: Adding a join to another table does not require MySQL (or any other RDBMS) to put the entire data set into memory, or even the entire result of the join. `WHERE` clauses on joined tables are only different from having the condition in the join itself if the join is an outer join and the condition accounts for a null value. Otherwise, it's functionally equivalent to using an ordinary inner join with the pertinent `WHERE` condition as part of that (or a later) join. Query optimization, which all RDBMS's do, is about respecting the fact that SQL represents relational calculus, not

Comment: (cont.) relational algebra. The optimizer will restructure its internal representation of your query to (ideally) reduce the amount of IO and CPU work that is required to fulfill the request.

Comment: I get that the RDBMS's primary job is to optimize queries and get data out fast. I've also worked with big data sets, and there's a point where you just have to come up with other solutions than building a complexly joined query because it doesn't perform fast enough. There's no silver bullet to DB Optimization, and I didn't mean to even scratch the surface on writing a guide to it. I was simply trying to point him in the right direction. I did however go over some general rules for normalization and (hopefully) made my response a little more clear (albeit, wordy). I feel that everything is

Comment: (cont.) accurate based on my personal experiences and research.

Comment: @Jim: Given that the primary issue I take with your statement (that there is a difference between designing indexes to accommodate joins and any *other* type of index, and that indexes for joins are somehow harder to design, and that joins will require that much more data be read into memory) are still there, I have to leave my downvote. While your current explanation does use more words, I do not believe it to be any more correct than it was originally. I certainly believe that you may have encountered performance issues with databases in the past that were solved by using a structure

Comment: (cont.) that was not fully normalized, but putting ideas like the possibility of needing to denormalize the data into the head of someone who's asking what all of this means is not wise, and doesn't give the reader the proper perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how to process the data in "chunks".  That means instead of simply trying to manipulate the entire data set, you need to break it into smaller more manageable pieces.  For example, if you had a table with 1 Billion records, a single update statement against the entire table would likely take a long time to complete, and may possibly bring the server to it's knees.

You could, however, issue a series of update statements within a loop that would update 20,000 records at a time.  Each iteration of the loop you would increment your range/counters/whatever to identify the next set of records.

Also, you commit your changes at the end of each loop, thereby allowing you to stop the process and continue where you left off.

This is just one aspect of managing large data sets.  You still need to know:

- how to perform backups
- proper indexing
- database maintenance

Answer (score 0):

[You can raed/learn how to handle large dataset with MySQL](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/07/05/working-with-large-data-sets-in-mysql/) But it is not equivalent to having actual experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Straight and simple answer: Study about partitioned database and find appropriate MySQL data structure types for large scale datasets similar with the partitioned database architecture.